# How to restart a Flink job from code

Tags: apache-flink

This seems to be a fairly simple problem but after several days of research I still couldn't figure a way to gracefully cancel a Flink job and restart it **from the code**

As a reference, there is a similar post: [Canceling Apache Flink job from the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139932/canceling-apache-flink-job-from-the-code/44293036#44293036), but it didn't tell how to get the JobManager, which has cancel() method that might help.

Someone can shed some lights on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think ,easiest approach to cancel flink job through code would be to use rest api .
See : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/monitoring/rest_api.html#job-cancellation

Then you can define **Restart Strategies** in main class of your flink-code. like

```
final int restartAttempts = configuration.getInteger(RESTART_ATTEMPTS, 3);
final int delayBtwAttempts = configuration.getInteger(RESTART_DELAY_IN_MILLIS, 3000);
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setRestartStrategy(fixedDelayRestart(restartAttempts, delayBtwAttempts));
```

See : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/restart_strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

We can pass configuration to flink env like:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setString(SavepointConfigOptions.SAVEPOINT_PATH, "//savepointPath");
configuration.setBoolean(SavepointConfigOptions.SAVEPOINT_IGNORE_UNCLAIMED_STATE, true);
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(
        flinkProperties.getIp(),
        flinkProperties.getPort(), configuration);
```